# How to transform different ways of storing JSON text strings

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I am making a Unity game to be used in WebGL and I need to store all the game dialogues / text in a JSON file for localization purposes. I am also using the Fungus framework inside Unity to help me build the narrative structure of dialogues.

The game is going to be wired to a platform using an API which works reading JSON language file in this way: Language > Key Name.

The fungus framework reads the dialogues using a JSON file using this way: Key Name > Language.

This is the format the fungus framework uses to read JSON files storing game language text. (My file looks like this... )

```
{  
   "string-key-1":{  
      "en":"Text for the 'string-key-1' key",
      "es":"Texto para la llave 'string-key-1'"
   },
   "string-key-2":{  
      "en":"Text or the 'string-key-2' key",
      "es":"Texto para la llave 'string-key-2'"
   }
}
```

This is the format the portal API uses to read JSON files storing game language text. (I want to take the first file and generate a new one looking like this)

```
{  
   "en":{  
      "string-key-1":"Text for the 'string-key-1' key",
      "string-key-2":"Text for the 'string-key-2' key"
   },
   "es":{  
      "string-key-1":"Texto para la llave 'string-key-1'",
      "string-key-2":"Texto para la llave 'string-key-2'"
   }
}
```

Is there a way I can take the first format (string keys > languages) and generate a new file in the format (languages > string keys) ?

Comment: Can you clarify what "bridge both of these so they work together" means? Do you want to create a data structure which contains everything from both?

Comment: Is this question asking how to parse a file that has a JSON object in it? It's really unclear about what you're having trouble with exactly. That would be the first place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you're having a string as input, and want to convert it to another string.
Here's a way:

1. Parse the string to an object (`Dictionary<StringKey, Dictionary<Language, Value>>`).
2. Convert the nested dictionary to a list of `{ StrKey, Language, Value }`
3. Group the list by item language
4. Convert the result back to a nested dictionary
5. Serialize the result dictionary to a string.

So follow it line by line,

```cs
var resultObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>(input)
    .SelectMany(key => key.Value.Select(str => new { StrKey = key.Key, Language = str.Key, Value = str.Value }))
    .GroupBy(item => item.Language)
    .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.ToDictionary(item => item.StrKey, item => item.Value));
var resultStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Formatting.Indented);
```